# Interactive Broker Java API returns nothing from historicalData

Tags: java, api, interactive-brokers

Supposed the below code would returns and print a list of historical market data like the open, close, high, low, volume. The connection to Interactive Broker API should be fine. But in Java console, it did not print the market data from callbacks. Looks like it did not go through the historicalData function. How do I activate that function and store the market data in an object?

```
id 1
-1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm.nj
-1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:cashfarm
-1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm
-1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:cashhmds
-1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:hkhmds
-1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds
-1 2158 Sec-def data farm connection is OK:secdefil
...
```

Sample Code:

```
    void run() {
        m_client.eConnect("localhost", 7497, 123);
        final EReader reader = new EReader(m_client, m_signal);
        reader.start();
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (m_client.isConnected()) {
                    m_signal.waitForSignal();
                    try {
                        reader.processMsgs();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void nextValidId(int orderId) {
        System.out.println("id "+orderId);
        nextOrderID = orderId;
        //Contract c = new StkContract("AAPL");
        Contract c = new Contract();
        c.symbol("EUR");
        c.exchange("IDEALPRO");
        c.secType("CASH");
        c.currency("USD");

        m_client.reqHistoricalData(1, c, 
                LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE)+ " 16:00:00",
                "1 D", "1 min", "MIDPOINT", 1, 1, false, null);
        m_client.reqMktData(1, c, "", false, false, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void error(int id, int errorCode, String errorMsg) {
        System.out.println(id + " " + errorCode + " " + errorMsg);
    }

    @Override
    public void historicalData(int reqId, String date, double open, double high, double low, double close, int volume, int count, double WAP, boolean hasGaps) {
        //if being run on the next calendar day, this works
        if (LocalDate.now().minusDays(1).format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE).equals(date)){
            this.date = date;
            this.high = high;
            this.low = low;
            this.open = open;
            this.close = close;
            System.out.println(date + " h: " + high + " l: " +low);
        }
        System.out.println("Requesting Data...");
        System.out.println(EWrapperMsgGenerator.historicalData(reqId, date, open, high, low, close, volume, count, WAP));
        System.out.println("Data Input Ended...");
    }
```

Comment: make sure api logging is on in the configure->api->settings tab and you should see everything sent back and forth to TWS.

Comment: I have tried to take a look at api logging under C:\Jts directory, but it does not contain the historical data feed details in there. I suppose the historicalData function does not run at all to print the OHLC data.

Comment: You can see if the request is logged it will look like `hh:mm:ss.sss <- 20`  Note 20 is the request type number for historical data.  The reply will be `time -> 17` and 17 is the number for a historical data reply.